# set the maximum allowed size of uploaded files globally

Tags: grails

Is there a way to set the max. allowed size of uploaded files *globally* in a Grails application, i.e. not just for one particular request or command/domain class property?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do so by setting the `maxUploadSize` property for the `CommonsMultipartResolver` in `Resources.groovy` like this:

```
multipartResolver(org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver) {
    maxUploadSize=2500000
}
```

Comment: the default implementation of this bean seems to be `ContentLengthAwareCommonsMultipartResolver`, are you sure changing it to `CommonsMultipartResolver` is wise?

Comment: It wasn't a conscious decision to make the change, I was going based on previous Spring experience and previous versions of Grails. I wasn't aware that it had changed since the 1.3.7 days.